# jUnits for backing bean with contructer

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4, jsf-1.2

I want to write jUnit test cases for methods which are in backing bean but the problems is that bean's constructer has some calls to "facesContext" methods. calls are like this

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().
  put(
    BEAN_NAME,
    BEAN_OBJECT
  );
```

If I write any test case it throws "NullPointerException". I know that it is because facesContext is not initialized.

For example If I have a method like this

```
public String disableFields() throws ApplicationException
{
  logger.info(empId);
  logger.info(relationShip.getRelationshipName());
  if(relationShip.getRelationshipName().equalsIgnoreCase("select"))
  {
    errorMessage="Please select relationship";
    Utils.addMessage(errorMessage, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
    return null;
  }


  showEmpName=true;// boolean value
  return null;
}
```

kindly suggest me with code of jUnit test case if possible......

please suggest any way to write jUnits test cases for these type of methods....I am using jsf 1.2..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need PowerMockito's feature for mocking static methods as explained here: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

Here's a working example:

```
import org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Utils.class)
public class AppTest {

  public static final String PLEASE_SELECT_RELATIONSHIP = "Please select relationship";

  @Test
  public void testDisableFields() throws Exception {

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Utils.class);

    Relationship relationShip = Mockito.mock(Relationship.class);
    App app = new App(1, relationShip);

    Mockito.when(relationShip.getRelationshipName()).thenReturn("SeLeCt");


    app.disableFields();

    Assert.assertThat(app.getErrorMessage(), IsEqual.equalTo(PLEASE_SELECT_RELATIONSHIP));

    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(1));
    Utils.addMessage(PLEASE_SELECT_RELATIONSHIP, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
  }

}
```

Comment: could you please suggets me how to write jUnit test case for above mentioned method, so that I can get an idea...I dont have much idea about jUnit.